# JSP не перенаправлят на другое JSP

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

Я новичок, возможно, вопрос покажется глупым. Взял готовый код из туториала по CRUD приложению. Попытался засунуть код в новый проект и немного изменить его. В исходном проекте открывалась страница index.jsp из нее по ссылке `<a href="<c:url value="/users" ></c:url>` приложение переходило на следующую страницу users.jsp. У меня при переходе по ссылке приложение выводит

> HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available.

[image: Структура проекта]

index.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Proselyte</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Proselyte presents</h3>
<br/>
test
<a href="<c:url value="/users" ></c:url>" target="_blank">Users list</a>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```html
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>CRUD</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.romanoff83.ivan.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Database Information -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>ru.romanoff83.ivan.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--userDao and UserService beans-->
    <bean id="userDao" class="ru.romanoff83.ivan.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userService" class="ru.romanoff83.ivan.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.romanoff83.ivan.controller"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

users.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="from" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Users Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="../../index.jsp">Back to main menu</a>

</body>
</html>

package ru.romanoff83.ivan.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import ru.romanoff83.ivan.model.User;
import ru.romanoff83.ivan.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class UsersController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersController.class);

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "userService")
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        logger.info("setUserService: " + userService);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        logger.info("after model.addAttribute: ");
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.userService.listUsers());
        logger.info("model.addAttribute: "+ this.userService.listUsers().size());
        return "users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBook(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        if(user.getId() == 0){
            this.userService.addUser(user);
        }else {
            this.userService.updateUser(user);
        }

        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removeBook(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        this.userService.removeUser(id);

        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @RequestMapping("edit/{id}")
    public String editBook(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.getUser(id));
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.userService.listUsers());

        return "users";
    }

//    @RequestMapping("bookdata/{id}")
//    public String bookData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
//        model.addAttribute("book", this.userService.getUser(id));
//
//        return "bookdata";
//    }
}
```

Comment: Пробовал debug дальше index.jsp код не проходит

Answer (score 0):

Внимательно посмотрел лог в Tomcat 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet .....
Выяснил что были проблемы с зависимостями. 
Не было spring-core, spring-web.
Так же надо было добавить в WEB_INF\lib\ все библиотеки как указанно [в ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227395/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherserv)